# check this is url or not in csv file

Tags: python

I want to remove the value from csv file which is not url: our df['url'] contains value like 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask' 'https://www.linkedin.com/feed/' '345', I want to remove 345.

```
def Find_url(string):
    url = re.findall('http[s]?://(?:[a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|[$-_@.&+]|[!*\(\), ]|(?:%[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]))+', string)
    return url



if __name__ == "__main__":
    file = pd.read_csv('url_file.csv')
    df =  pd.DataFrame(file)
    for i in range(len(df)):
        url = Find_url(df.loc[i]['url'])
        df.loc[i]['url']=url
df.to_csv('clean_url.csv')
```

Sample input:

```
 'https://www.zaubacorp.com/company/HINDUSTAN-CABLES-LTD/L31300WB1952GOI020560'
'http://www.indianrailways.gov.in/railwayboard/view_section.jsp?lang=0&id=0
1
304
365'
 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Railway_Board'
 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Railway_Board#History'
```

I want output like this Sample output:

```
 'https://www.zaubacorp.com/company/HINDUSTAN-CABLES-LTD/L31300WB1952GOI020560'
'http://www.indianrailways.gov.in/railwayboard/view_section.jsp?lang=0&id=0
 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Railway_Board'
 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Railway_Board#History'
```

Comment: So what's the question? Are there errors? Then please include the full exception of the error. Please include sample input that reproduces the problem. It runs but nothing appears to change? Then give us sample input and the output it produces, as well as the output you expected it to produce instead.

Comment: No it not gives the the error but it does not remove the value which is not url, I want to only those value which is url

Comment: Then please explicitly state so in your question. Make it a proper [mcve], with sample input data and expected output data. The easier you make it for experts to reproduce your issue, the faster you'll get your answer, and the more useful your question becomes to others in the future. That's the point of Stack Overflow, to be a repository for future visitors to find the same answers.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I put the sample input and sample output

Comment: Please be explicit; what output do you get instead?

Comment: yes I already mention on sample output i want to remove the value like 1
304
365 which is not url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`urllib.parse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urlparse) from the standard library to try and parse a string as a URL with necessary attributes.

```
from io import StringIO
from urllib.parse import urlparse
import pandas as pd

def url_validator(x):
    try:
        result = urlparse(x)
        # check non-empty attributes
        return all((result.scheme, result.netloc, result.path))
    except AttributeError:
        return False

mystr = StringIO("""https://www.zaubacorp.com/company/HINDUSTAN-CABLES-LTD/L31300WB1952GOI020560
http://www.indianrailways.gov.in/railwayboard/view_section.jsp?lang=0&id=0
1
304
365
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Railway_Board
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Railway_Board#History""")

# replace mystr with 'file.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(mystr, header=None, names=['values'])

# apply filter based on checker function
df = df[df['values'].apply(url_validator)]

print(df)

                                              values
0  https://www.zaubacorp.com/company/HINDUSTAN-CA...
1  http://www.indianrailways.gov.in/railwayboard/...
5        https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Railway_Board
6  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Railway_Board#Hi...
```